# Multiple SELECT queries with different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

First of all I want to clarify that I'm pretty new to SQL and coding in general so I guess for some of you this question would seem rather basic (not to say stupid).
I have a table with the followimng columns: id, date, device_type, browser, browser_version, ip, visitor_id, ads_viewed, ads_clicked.
I'm trying to create a query that will group a visitor into three groups (below) and return
only the IPs for each visitor that’s in both group A and B.

A. visitor that has viewed more than 2 ads.

B. visitor that has clicked an ad.

C. all other visitors.

I've Tried:

```
SELECT group_a, group_b FROM
(SELECT visitor_id as group_a FROM adsdata
GROUP BY visitor_id
HAVING SUM(ads_viewed) > 2) AS group_a,
(SELECT visitor_id as group_b FROM adsdata
GROUP BY visitor_id
HAVING SUM(ads_clicked) > 0) AS group_b
GROUP BY group_a, group_b;
```

But that gets me way too many rows of data, it seems I cant group the data correctly.
Also, it doesn't fill the 3 groups requirement.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, it is not really possible to answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and review [ask]. In particular table descriptions (DDL), and sample data, as text - **no images**, and the expected results of that data.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to stackoverflow, and I don't know if the solution works but:

1. Take a good look at your conditionals, you are selecting data from a table, so I think you are selecting repeated data according to the group.
2. If the code I send you does not work, you should look at this documentation:
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-conditional.html

If it doesn't work for you, I'm sorry, but it's the most I can help you: c

```
SELECT group_a, group_b FROM

(SELECT visitor_id FROM adsdata
HAVING SUM(ads_viewed) > 2) AS group_a,

(SELECT visitor_id FROM adsdata
HAVING 2 > SUM(ads_clicked) > 0) AS group_b

GROUP BY group_a, group_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little reflection I think I have an idea of what you need. You need to accumulate each category in a sub query the determine the group in the outer query. However, it seems your requirements still have a ambiguity. How do you classify a visitor both 2 or more viewed ads and a 1 clicked ad.

```
with visitors (id, ads_viewed, ads_clicked) as 
     ( values (1,null,null) 
            , (2,1,null)
            , (2,null,2) 
            , (3,3,1) 
            , (4,1,1)   
            , (5,1,0)               
     ) 
select   
       case when ads_viewed > 2 then 'Group A'
            when ads_clicked > 0 then 'Group B'
            else 'Group C'
       end 
     , id
     , ads_viewed
     , ads_clicked
  from (
         select id
              , sum( coalesce(ads_viewed,0))  ads_viewed
              , sum( coalesce(ads_clicked,0)) ads_clicked
           from visitors
          group by id
       ) s
order by case when ads_viewed > 2 then 'A'
              when ads_clicked > 0 then 'B'
              else 'C'
         end  
       , id;
```